# Getting errors when updating the source list

Tags: apt

Recently I installed Kali and BT5 tools on my Ubuntu 12.04. At that I edited source.list file. When I issue `sudo apt-get update` it is exiting showing errors occured and they are ignored. What can be the problem for this ? ? I hope following last lines of the output will be informative.

```
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 515 kB in 38s (13.3 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://64.repository.backtrack-linux.org/dists/revolution/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
shivkesh@Keshav:~$
```

Comment: It looks like the files you are trying to download are the problem, not the software updater. They may not exist or are no longer supported. If you install software that isn't from the Ubuntu repositories, you can't be sure it is properly supported.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `uname -a` as well as your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to your post?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the repository you are using is not compatible with Ubuntu. You have added a repository for BackTrack Linux, which is not Ubuntu. As explained in the [BackTrack FAQ](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Why_cant_I_just_add_the_Backtrack_repositories_to_my_Ubuntu_install_or_the_Ubuntu_repositories_to_my_Backtrack_install_.3F%20%20does%20not%20include%20an%20entry%20for%20your%20Ubuntu):

> **Why cant I just add the Backtrack repositories to my Ubuntu install or the Ubuntu repositories to my Backtrack install ?**
>
> We highly recommend against this action because Backtrack tools are built with many custom features, libraries and kernel. **We have no way of knowing how they will perform on a non Backtrack distribution, plus you will very quickly break your install**.
> Also if you chose to add the ubuntu repositories to your Backtrack install, you will most certainly break your entire Backtrack install very quickly.
> We do a lot of testing to ensure that all packages in our repo will work together without causing problems.
> If you decide on this course of action you do so entirely at your own risk and the backtrack team will not offer any support in any way.

The specific error you are getting also shows that the BackTrack repositories don't have the same structure as the Ubuntu ones and therefore, `apt-get` is not finding the expected files.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13_amd64.deb  and downgrading apt to the one BackTrack have.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i /path/apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.13_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Increase cache limit

   ```
   echo APT::Cache-Limit "60000000"; >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
   ```
3. Update again.

Comment: Please don't recommend downgrading `apt`, that can have all sorts of bad effects on your system.